# Find the limit of $P_s(n)^k$ in a markov chain

Tags: limits, markov-chains

I have a markov chain like this

$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 P_{s}(n) \\
 P_{f}(n)
 \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b \\
 1-a & 1-b 
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 P_{s}(n-1) \\
 P_{f}(n-1) 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

where

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 P_{s}(0) \\
 P_{f}(0)
 \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 1
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and I need to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P_{s}(n)^k,$$ for some constant $k$, if there is any limit.

I tried to manually calculate $P_{s}(n)^k$, in which $k=6, a=0.83, b=0.625$, and I noticed that the curve seems to have a limit (I'm not sure though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Do not think about the $k$ we will try to calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} P_s(n)$ first and then take it to the $k^\text{th}$ power.

We have $p_n = Tp_{n-1}$ if we have convergence we should get $p_\infty = Tp_\infty$ or

$$\begin{bmatrix} P_s(\infty)\\P_f(\infty)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\1-a & 1-b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} P_s(\infty)\\P_f(\infty)\end{bmatrix}.$$

This equation is the eigenvalue equation for the eigenvalue $1$. Solve this equation for 
$$\begin{bmatrix} P_s(\infty)\\P_f(\infty)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! However, to be honest, I'm not a Math major and I'm sorry that I totally got no idea about linear algebras. I got this equation from my research in computer science.

Comment: You simply have to solve the system for $P_s(\infty)$ and $P_f(\infty)$ it is a simple system with two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean. Let me see how to solve this. Thank you!